# Bonita (7.1) returns unathorized process

Tags: bonita

We are working with version 7.1 Bonita and execute with WSO2 (4.9.0) and Rest Client first a loginprocess and then  a process it  returns unauthorized, it is send as a parameter of the request with name Cookie, Are we doing something bad?

A greet

Answer (score 0):

If it returns Unauthorized you are doing something bad. :)

To start a case via REST execute the following calls within the same HTTP Session:

`POST http://localhost:8080/bonita/loginservice?username=walter.bates&password=bpm` with an empty payload
and then `POST http://localhost:8080/bonita/API/bpm/case` with the following payload:

```
{  
   "processDefinitionId":"5777042023671752656",
   "variables":[  
      {  
         "name":"stringVariable",
         "value":"aValue"
      },
      {  
         "name":"dateVariable",
         "value":349246800000
      },
      {  
         "name":"numericVariable",
         "value":5
      }
   ]
}
```

More information about can be found [here](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bpm-api-849#case)